# Unable to load gem during runtime - cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile, faker

I have the following declaration in my Gemfile

> gem 'foo', :git => 'git@github.com:bar/foo.git'

After I run bundle install, it is able to retrieve the gem under the following folder

> $ ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@samples/bundler/gems/foo-4dc3d7bf8271

But using the gem in my program using require 'foo' and running it raises the following problem.

> custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- foo
>   (LoadError)

How do I resolve this?

EDIT

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i686-linu
x
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i686-li
nux
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/
custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- foo (LoadError)
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.
9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

Comment: hrm, i usually don't have to require a gem but one other thing i see in the above is that the gem name should be followed with a version number.  foo-1.3.4, is that just because of your example?

Comment: foo-4dc3d7bf8271 - This is because I forked a project and made some changes to it, hence I am trying to use this gem directly from github

Comment: Add a line `puts $:` (or use `Rails.logger.debug $:` if its Rails application) before your requirement and examine, whether your gem path in a list or not. Also check, is file `foo.rb` located within its path, it may have slightly different name.

Comment: @Nash - I get the above error added as part of the question, when I try to run my sample ruby program.

Comment: Maybe, you need specify how to require that gem like: `gem 'dylansm-wirble', :require => 'wirble'`

Comment: @taro I don't think that's the problem. Because if you look at the LOAD_PATH above, there's any Rails-related gem path there (`active_record` and so on), which leads me to assumption that bundler hasn't been run at all (or maybe it's not a Rails application)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `require 'bundler/setup'` is called before you require any gem from your `Gemfile`. But in Rails case it should happen for sure, because `rails server` calls `config/boot.rb`, which contains such line.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was stuck on the same issue for hours. Thanks a lot.